# how do I completely remove Subversion from a Mac/RadRails?

Tags: svn

UGH.  I installed the subversion plugin for RadRails so tha I could commit changes to my SVN repository.

But when I now try to do an script/plugin install git://...

I get an error:

svn: This client is too old to work with working copy

I removed the plugins, removed all the .svn files, removed the opt/subversion removed the symlinks....

I still get the error!

This has paralyzed the environment, any suggestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up doing a complete reinstall of SVN and also discovered that RadRails isn't a real terminal so that was causing a huge problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you remove all .svn directories from a working copy, it's no longer a working copy, so it can't be too old.

You should check the version of Subversion that's supported by Subversive to the output of `svn --version`.

The executable / tool that complains about "client too old" will have to be updated.

The cause is that the working copy format can be updated by new subversion clients, and it will do this without asking/letting you know by design. The older tool detects that the working copy has been upgraded, and bails out because it can't read the newer format.

Any 1.6.x client can interoperate with any other 1.6.x client on the same working copy. Using a 1.5.x client with a 1.6.y client causes the 1.5.x client to error out.

If you need to update the svn commandline client, check out the [openCollab Downloads](http://www.open.collab.net/downloads/community/)

Comment: hi, I downloaded 1.6.x from openCollab...my RadRails when I try to run generate/plugin install says I need a new subversion client....so....not sure what the deal is.  I removed subclipse and all the .svn files...I just want to be able to start getting from github!

Comment: Did you run `svn --version` after installing the newer version? IIRC it doesn't replace the default instance, but leaves it up to the user to modify PATH or switch the default in other ways.